# Angular - why is the scope not updated inside of this function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to figure out why when the console tells me one thing but angular's output to html tells me another.

Code

```
angular.module('global',[]);

angular.module('global').controller('thisTestController', thisTestController);
function thisTestController() {
  var tc = this;  
  tc.status = "not loaded";

  function activate() {

    var background = new Image();
    background.onload = function () {
        tc.status = "loaded";
        console.log(tc.status);
    };
    background.src = 'http://placehold.it/350x150';

  }

  activate();

}
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-app="global">
     <div ng-controller="thisTestController as tc">Status = {{tc.status}}</div>
  </body>
```

Result

```
Console.log - loaded
HTML - Status = not loaded
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wxja7smqOJiSbUi7mfu4?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs service callback to update scope of controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931689/angularjs-service-callback-to-update-scope-of-controller)

Comment: read about `$digest` http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: to trigger the $digest safety, you can use `$timeout` http://plnkr.co/edit/ZRDCroSxPLWHKd6YjHVC?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind your controller with $scope, like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CV7rgBGQMnRlNDnYSQIq?p=preview

```
angular.module('global', []);

angular.module('global').controller('thisTestController', thisTestController);

function thisTestController($scope) {
  var tc = this;
  tc.status = "not loaded";

  function activate() {

    var background = new Image();
    background.onload = function() {
      tc.status = "loaded";
      $scope.$apply();
      console.log(tc.status);
    };
    background.src = 'http://placehold.it/350x150';

  }

  activate();

}
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to use `$apply()` without the function argument because behind the scenes they wrap the function in a `try,catch` and in turn pass it to the $exceptionHandler service. Also, you should always have $apply in a timeout because of conflicts if something else is updating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$scope` and `$scope.$apply` to update values after the context has been rendered. `tc` (`this`) has no context in the lifecycle of the controller. In other words, your tc assignment is really just the function itself. Not the binding context for the controller.

I have a forked version of your plnkr with a simple example to get it working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fghSbSsarBbM0zv5EzoB?p=preview

Docs for `$scope` and `$apply` can be found here:

[angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)