# Manually call $scope.$apply raise error on ajax call - Error: [$rootScope:inprog]

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-scope

I tried to use Angular Material `md-autocomplete`, the suggestion list was retrieved from Service Host via **Ajax Call**. Because of **Delaying response**, the `$scope` variable **was not updating the UI Properly**, it updates only is there is any event occur in the specific control. For Example Focus Sent Out and again Click the Control, then it updates the UI with the new value.

My Exact issue snapshot is posted in [md-items is not updating the suggesion list properly in md-autocomplete Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624977/md-items-is-not-updating-the-suggesion-list-properly-in-md-autocomplete-angular)

After a long time of google I got a theoretical solution is `$scope.$apply()` - reference got from [Angular controller scope not updating after jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127709/angular-controller-scope-not-updating-after-jquery-ajax-call)

But I got an error **Error: [$rootScope:inprog]...** Kindly assist me how to fix the error

The Complete Sample Source Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Person to Select:</p>

<md-autocomplete
          ng-disabled="isDisabled"
          md-no-cache="noCache"
          md-selected-item="selectedItem"
          md-search-text-change="searchTextChange()"
          md-search-text="searchText"
          md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)"
          md-items="item in Person"
          md-item-text="item.Name"
          md-min-length="0"
          placeholder="Which is your favorite Person?">
        <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.Name}} - {{item.City}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
          No Person matching "{{searchText}}" were found.
        </md-not-found>
      </md-autocomplete>
      <br/>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $q) {

        $scope.searchText = "";
        $scope.Person = [];
        $scope.selectedItem = [];
        $scope.isDisabled = false;
        $scope.noCache = false;

        $scope.selectedItemChange = function (item) {
            alert("Item Changed");
        }
        $scope.searchTextChange = function () {

            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php",
                params: {
                    uid: $scope.searchText
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.Person = response.data.records;
                });
            });
        }

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

actually I'm using localhost for ajax call, Here I mentioned the sample Ajax URL is http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php for your reference to get data.

> Note: I need to use the `$scope.$apply()` within the Ajax Call without an error **Error: [$rootScope:inprog]...**

Kindly assist me... how to fix.

The Snapshot of Browser

[image]

Comment: @MartijnWelker is right. Your [Question #35624977](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35624977) is an asynchronous issue. (Values can't be returned **before** a promise is resolved.) `$apply()` won't fix that problem.

Comment: @georgeawg can you have any idea to resolve this issue pls?

Comment: Accept the answer from @MartijnWelker and write a new question that describes what you are **actually** trying to accomplish, include the desired behavior, a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @georgeawg I'm creating a new question. Once post is done, then I close this question by accepting his answer.

Comment: @georgeawg I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652828/http-issue-values-cant-be-returned-before-a-promise-is-resolved-in-angular-m which describes the issue details with my trial and error attempt history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.$apply` is automatically called by Angular when you use a `$` function, so you don't have to call it yourself, the reason your UI isn't updating must be somewhere else.

Comment: Then how to update the new values in the autocomplete list? 

In the Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127709/angular-controller-scope-not-updating-after-jquery-ajax-call - they are suggesting to call $scope.$apply() manually to update the UI.

Comment: He has to use $apply() because he is using jQuery's `$.post`, you don't have to because you're using Angular's `$http`

Comment: Make a new question regarding that exact issue with details, this one is answered.

Comment: Kindly visit the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624977/md-items-is-not-updating-the-suggesion-list-properly-in-md-autocomplete-angular here I posted the screen shot with issues using actual data.

Comment: @MartijnWelker is right. Your [Question #35624977](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35624977) is an asynchronous issue. (Values can't be returned **before** a promise is resolved.) `$apply()` won't fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the way you need to do it,try the `$scope.$applyAsync`

Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync).

Answer (score 1):

Angular usually calls the $digest, $watch internally to bind the scope variable.

In your case, You have to manually invoke any of the event listeners to bind the data value.

Try using $watch or $apply in your scope variable

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.messageToUser = "You are done!";

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.messageToUser = "Timeout called!";
        });
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: refer this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673404/error-ngareq-from-angular-controller