# How to update angularjs $scope from $.get jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, google-contacts-api

I am trying to use the following code and use `$scope`:

```
var scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";

setTimeout(authorize(), 20);

function authorize() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthorization);
}
invitePeersController.gmailContacts = [];
function handleAuthorization(authorizationResult) {
    if (authorizationResult && !authorizationResult.error) {
        $.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=" + authorizationResult.access_token + "&max-results=50000&v=3.0",
            function(response){
                //process the response here
                console.log(response);
                var jsonChildData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( response.feed.entry));
                for(var i=0; i<jsonChildData.length;i++){
                    try {
                        var item = {};
                        var name = JSON.stringify(jsonChildData[i].title.$t);
                        var email = JSON.stringify(jsonChildData[i].gd$email[0].address);

                        if(name.substring(1, name.length-1) && email.substring(1, email.length-1)){
                         item ["name"] = name.substring(1, name.length-1);
                         item ["email"] = email.substring(1, email.length-1);
                         item ["id"] =  email.substring(1, email.length-1).replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
                        invitePeersController.gmailContacts.push(item);
                        }
                }
                catch(err) {
                 // console.log("Something went terribly wrong while trying to fetch Gmail Contacts Data");
                }
            }


            InvitePeersService.setGmailContactsData(invitePeersController.gmailContacts);
                    console.log(invitePeersController.gmailContacts);
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        $scope.gmailData = invitePeersController.gmailContacts;
                        console.log($scope.gmailData);
                    })


                });
            }
        }

    }
```

I can get the response in `$scope` but cannot get the data elsewhere.

How can I use that value in `$scope`?

Tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127709/angular-controller-scope-not-updating-after-jquery-ajax-call), and applied `$scope.$apply()` but it is not working.

Comment: when you do `console.log(invitePeersController.gmailContacts);`, does it log data ?

Comment: @anoop Yes, it does.

Comment: is there any error in console,? are you injecting `$scope` controller?, or is this a `service` ?and as a suggestion, you should use `$http.get()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the following block:

```
InvitePeersService.setGmailContactsData(invitePeersController.gmailContacts);
console.log(invitePeersController.gmailContacts);
$scope.$apply(function () {
  $scope.gmailData = invitePeersController.gmailContacts;
  console.log($scope.gmailData);
})
```

in the

```
function(response){
```

block, so that the `invitePeersController.gmailContacts` is initialized - as the response comes in a *callback* function.

Therefore:

```
var scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";

setTimeout(authorize(), 20);

function authorize() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthorization);
}
invitePeersController.gmailContacts = [];
function handleAuthorization(authorizationResult) {
  if (authorizationResult && !authorizationResult.error) {
    $.get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=' + authorizationResult.access_token + '&max-results=50000&v=3.0',
      function (response) {
        //process the response here
        console.log(response);
        var jsonChildData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.feed.entry));
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonChildData.length; i++) {
          try {
            var item = {};
            var name = JSON.stringify(jsonChildData[i].title.$t);
            var email = JSON.stringify(jsonChildData[i].gd$email[0].address);

            if (name.substring(1, name.length - 1) && email.substring(1, email.length - 1)) {
              item ['name'] = name.substring(1, name.length - 1);
              item ['email'] = email.substring(1, email.length - 1);
              item ['id'] = email.substring(1, email.length - 1).replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, '');
              invitePeersController.gmailContacts.push(item);
            }

            InvitePeersService.setGmailContactsData(invitePeersController.gmailContacts);
            console.log(invitePeersController.gmailContacts);
            $scope.$apply(function () {
              $scope.gmailData = invitePeersController.gmailContacts;
              console.log($scope.gmailData);
            })
          }
          catch (err) {
            // console.log("Something went terribly wrong while trying to fetch Gmail Contacts Data");
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Still the same.