# Angular bind non-Angular Event to scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is it possible to bind a non-angular event to a $scope-Function?

I have a DIV. In this DIV, I'm not allowed to bind the ngClick-Event and I should bind the "customclick"-Event. So I tried the following but obviously this executes the function on $apply rather than telling the framework to use the function as the eventhandler:

```
<div id="myCustomDiv" customclick="{{ setSelectedTab() }}">
  ...
</div>
```

Is this even possible or can $scope-Functions only bind to angular-Directives? I could do it in the controller with $(element).bind but I'd rather have this part in the view where it belongs.

Comment: Just write `customclick` directive.

Comment: maybe not allowed was the wrong expression. It's just not the event I want to listen to as this component throws a customclick event in special cases and ngClick doesn't capture them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How do I access the $scope variable in browser's console using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-scope-variable-in-browsers-console-using-angularjs) for detailed examples of accessing `$scope` from non-Angular sources.

In your case, I believe the following will work:

```
<div id="myCustomDiv" 
     customclick="angular.element('#myCustomDiv').scope().setSelectedTab()">
  ...
</div>
```

This approach requires that you *not* run Angular in [Production Mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production) so that you have access to the `scope()` function.