# Plain JavaScript to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello is there someone who knows:
How can I execute an AngularJs method from plain javascript. =)
Thanks.!!

```
myApp.controller("someController",["$scope",function($scope){
  //Some code was here
  $scope.a = valueA;
  $scope.b = valueB
});
```

and a bit later in the code want to execute a function that when valid could execute an IF and if thats the case will execute my AngularJS controller or what ever.

```
function Clicked(){
if( was clicked correctly ){
    //execute my Controller and send some data to add to the DOM
}
```

Comment: If you want to execute some thing in a button click why going for angular controller, write a javascript method.

Comment: why would you want to do that, whats the use case ?

Comment: [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-angular-scope-variable-in-browsers-console). But **why**?

Comment: Because what I want to do it's to connect a small game I have in Phaser Framework with some external Elements that I have made in AngularJS. Think about it like a TV just that the bottoms and controllers are in Phaser and the Screen it's the Angular part. So basically when something happens in the Phaser part I want to communicated to the Angular part. =)
Well this is my idea Hope I am clear and helpful to others.!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25569492/3986800

This is the solution, I answer in another post in stack

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think that's what you really want. Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick . You want your HTML elements to trigger a function inside your controller.

Comment: Thanks. But NO. because what I want to execute it's NOT inside of the DOM, it's inside a CANVAS element from JavaScript.

Comment: OK, relax. So you could use @RGrahams response, or maybe build up your canvas from your AngularJS controller and then, since you're inside the controller, have more easy access to it.

Comment: hehehe. Sorry thanks.!! ^^
I knew I could do that but I wanted to know if there was anyway I could executed from the outside of Angular so I could leave my controller light and simple. =)
By the way thanks Really.!!