# ng-show expression ... how to debug it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

I have the following code

```
<span ng-show="form.email.$error.unique">Email already exists</span>
```

This is working correctly and I am able to see the span element if the email entered in the "email" input field already exists in our db.

However if I go into chrome console. and then type

```
form.email.$error
```

it says undefined.

I can type in

```
form.email
```

and it shows me

```
​<input name=​"email" ng-model=​"model.email" required class=​"ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-unique">
```

So the question is why can't I see $error in chrome console? this value definitely exists because angular is reading it and based on the value it is deciding whether to show the span or not.

Edit:: Upon further reading documentation, I feel that the directive which checks whether email is valid or not... sets the validity on the controller object (4th parameter . $setValidity )

but somehow the UI reads that $error from the UI element .

so that's very confusing as to what is the actual workflow... where is the $error being set and from where it is being read.

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: I'm unsure how to do it with the console, I would just output that variable to the browser above the span.

Comment: When you type form.email in the console it's showing you an element from the DOM, which doesn't have an $error property. Angular creates a FormController and attaches that to the scope. That form controller is what defines the $error property.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of debugging in the console, a useful technique to use is to just output the variable in the view:{{form.email.$error.unique}}. Put this above or below your input element and watch the value dynamically change as you type into it.

Comment: yes I can do that... but I still want to know how to access the value from the console.

Comment: Also.. what I am fundamentally not clear on... is that the directive is setting the $setValidity on the controller object. and the ng-show is reading it from the form.elem.$error. So what I don't understand is how are these two connected.

Comment: This might work to access form.email.$error.unique from the broswer console (using jQuery): $('form[name="formName"]').scope().form.email.$error.unique;

Check out this: page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-angular-scope-variable-in-browsers-console

Answer (score 5):

Download the **AngularJS Batarang** Plugin for Chrome. After enabling it you can inspect any element and in the console `$scope` will be the scope of the selected element.
You can then inspect your mentioned `span` and type in console `$scope.form.email.$error.unique`and you'll get the current value of it.


**Alternatively** if you dont want to install that plugin (I would prefer installing it) you can get via javascript the current scope like `angular.element(document.getElementById(...)).scope()`  and then inspect that scope. 
(Of course you can get the element on other ways then per `document.getElementById(...))`

Comment: without this, it is not possible to get accesss to variables defined in angular funtions (directive,service,factory,controller)

Comment: I find myself in the unfortunate circumstance of needing to diagnose a bug in a legacy AngularJS 1.8.2 app in production, so adding debug output to the view is not an option for me. I tried both of these methods (as well as several other plugins), and scope is always `undefined`. Any suggestions? Should these tools and techniques still work in 2023?

Comment: Aha! If I first call `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()` from my console, all of these tools and techniques work!