# AngularJS - How to access a function from Chrome inspector, which is defined in a controller but not attached to $scope

Tags: angularjs

I am just curious about whether it is possible. I have read this post [How to access the angular $scope variable in browser's console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-angular-scope-variable-in-browsers-console) , so that I already know how to invoke the functions attached to a $scope from Chrome Console.

Say, I have a piece of code as follows(btw, I take the suggestions from [AngularJS style guide for teams](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide) and [AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide)):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("appClubS")
        .controller("userRegisterCtrl", userRegisterController);

    userRegisterController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$log', 'userFactory', 'passwordValidator'];

    function userRegisterController($scope, $location, $log, userFactory, passwordValidator) {

        // attach variables & functions to $scope here

        function validateUserInfo(userInfo) {
            // definition of function body
        }

    }

})();
```

Is there a way to access function validateUserInfo from Chrome Console? Thanks in advance.

Comment: for temporary debugging purposes, you can just attach it to the window object somewhere in your userRegisterController function: 

window.validateUserInfo = validateUserInfo