# How to know what a filter is filtering?

Tags: angularjs

I need to do a `console.log` of a filter which is actually a finder, I have this

```
<input type="search" ng-model="query">
```

and in my controller I declare it this way

```
$scope.query = '';
```

if I do `console.log($scope.query)` nothing happens once I type in the search box, so how can I know what the filter is filtering ?

Comment: Reference the following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-angular-scope-variable-in-browsers-console), you can either do it through console or install some tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to observe what is being sent to the filter, how about adding a [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) on your query variable?

```
$scope.$watch('query', function(val) {
   console.log(val);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lj1vxwud/2/