# Can I manually modify a variable of a JavaScript object at runtime?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

This is a silly question, but I was working on an AngularJS app (a simple school project), and wanted to know if there was a way to modify the JavaScript object once it's running in chrome from Chrome's Developer tools.  Basically, I have a character and a monster, and I wanted to edit the strength of them in the fight to speed up my debugging process (to avoid setting the value in the source code and then refreshing the page).

My guess is there isn't a way to do that because it could become some "security problem", but I just wasn't sure.

---

Edit:  This is the  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-angular-scope-variable-in-browsers-console).  I just didn't know how to search for it.  :)

Comment: For editing with AngularJS, drop a line of _debugger;_ in your code and you can inspect (hover over) an object, observe all properties, and it'll pause your browser's JS execution until you step through/into or continue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Hit F12
2. go to the `console` tab
3. start executing any javascript.

`character.strength = 12` or whatever will work as long as `character` is globally available.

Comment: k, Maybe I should edit my question.  Would you have any idea of how to find the AngularJS $scope variable?

Comment: @JacobHolloway http://stackoverflow.com/a/13744085/845280

Comment: I found that right after I asked.  :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tons of help came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-angular-scope-variable-in-browsers-console).  I just didn't know how to search for it.  :)

The console is my friend...

1. Hit F12
2. Go to the console tab
3. Start executing any javascript:

---

To get the angular stuff, I needed to:

1. get to the controller
2. grab the scope,
3. then the object
4. then the value...

---

So this worked perfectly!

```
angular.element('[ng-controller=BattleCtrl]').scope().monster.currentHealth = 25
```

Thanks for your guidance.