# ondragstart, ondragover,onstart - $scope is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angularjs-digest

My task is to process the dropped text using angular. I keep getting this error `$scope is not defined` on drag and drop events. Any idea how to fix this?

I already looked into angular drag and drop libraries. They don't allow drag and drop for simple text. Most of them work with lists. Let me know if there is one that works for this task

Here is the plunker:

[`http://plnkr.co/edit/egKL13hsHka6RiX4UfSS?p=preview`][1]

here is the controller:

```
var app = angular.module("test",  []);
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',function  ($scope) {
   $scope.nouns = ['guitar'];
   $scope.verbs = ['play'];
   $scope.allowDrop= function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
   };
   $scope.drag=  function (ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
   };    
   $scope.drop=  function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        if(ev.target.id =='verb' && $scope.verbs.indexOf(data) != -1){
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
        else{
            alert(data + ' is not a ' + ev.target.id +'. Try again');
        }            
    };      
  }]);
```

Comment: In your html you are using `$scope.drag`.  You don't need the `$scope`.  Just use `drag($event)`.

Comment: Now it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: drag is not defined , allowDrop is not defined".

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid.  You can't do what you were doing in Angular the way you are doing it.  i.e. you can't put $scope functions in regular attributes.  You have to use the `ng-<event>` versions.  And there aren't any for drag and drop events.  You need to use something like [ngDraggable](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngDraggable)

Comment: I already looked into ng-Draggable like libraries. I can't find one that allows drag and drop simple text. They all work with lists or Html elements.

Comment: If you surround your text with a `<span>text</span>` element then it will be an HTML element and maybe you can use the ng-draggable library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$scope` object will not available in **"Outside angular context"**.
Whenever you want to access angular scope in JavaScript (Outside angular world) then you need to get the `scope` of by getting the DOM of that element & then access the scope of it like `angular.element(document.getElementById('testApp'))` which is nothing but scope of the body.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lntx15ufV9ux0GWBrzQb?p=preview)

Refer this [**SO answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-angular-scope-variable-in-browsers-console) to get access to the scope outside angular context.

Comment: @kumaro glad to help you..it would be more elegant if you do this by using directive..

Answer (score 2):

a shorter one based on @pankaj-parkar answer :

```
<div draggable="true" ondrag="angular.element(this).scope().on_drag(event)"></div>
```