# How to access the *angular 2* components' data in the browser's console?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-console

I have a DisplayComponent and I'd like to see it's data in the browser's/developer's console. How can I see it?

Example from [Angular2 step by step guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/displaying-data.html):

```
function DisplayComponent() {
  this.myName = "Alice";
}
```

How do I see `this.myName` in the browser's/developer's **console**?

* Please note that this is a question about **Angular 2** and not Angular 1. The [suggested solution for AngularJS (Angular 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744085/435605) doesn't work.

Comment: I've created [the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3689) for your problem

Comment: Good blog for debuging angular 2 apps I have found here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/debugging-angular-2-applications It pointed me to augury.angular.io which is great tool for ng2 apps development. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HBM9gXLSgQc5eT9dTv3d?p=preview). So basically what you need to do at this moment:

1. Add [test_lib.js](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.37/test_lib.dev.js) to the page
2. Add `ELEMENT_PROBE_BINDINGS` to your app bindings.

   ```
   import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2'
   import { ELEMENT_PROBE_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/debug'
   import { App } from './app'

   bootstrap(App,ELEMENT_PROBE_BINDINGS )
       .catch(err => console.error(err));
   ```
3. Use `ng.probe` method to check the element:

   ```
   const app = document.querySelector('my-app');
   const debugElement = ng.probe(app);
   ```

Comment: ELEMENT_PROBE_BINDINGS does not exist in new versions of angular2, it was renamed to ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS and there are only few mentions of this in github source of ng2 lib, it seems that it disappeared completely. And there is no angular2/debug anymore too. Could you actualise your answer please?

Comment: So the actual state (tested on angular4) is, that in dev mode (ng serve), you don need to make steps 1. and 2. You can jump right into step 3.
Happy coding :)

Comment: how can I trigger a change when I update a value from the console?

Answer (score 2):

`var componentTag     = document.querySelector('.component-tag');
var componentDetails = window.ng.probe(kitchenSink);
componentDetails.componentInstance`

For more details see https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/debugging-angular-2-applications#console

Answer (score -4):

Did u try simple console command?

```
console.log(this.myName)
```

Hope I understand ur question correctly.

Comment: I think he wants to get component from console of developer tools. Something like: `document.querySelector('.compnent-selector').component.myName;`

Comment: Right. What do I need to write in the developer's console?