# Is there an Angular 2 equivalent for 'angular.element($0).scope()'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, google-chrome-devtools

So for my sins I'm on an Angular 2 project. I use `angular.element($0).scope()` all the time on my old Angular 1 work to inspect an element and see what's on the scope at that point in the dev tools. This is super useful, is there something similar in Angular 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Augury is a great suggestion. If you want direct access use

```
ng.probe($0)
```

See also

- [Get ComponentRef from DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804834/get-componentref-from-dom-element/34175224#34175224)
- [How to access the *angular 2* components' data in the browser's console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052432/how-to-access-the-angular-2-components-data-in-the-browsers-console/32749562#32749562)
- [how to access Angular2 component specific data in console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233572/how-to-access-angular2-component-specific-data-in-console/35233711#35233711)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Augury? Link: https://github.com/rangle/augury