# What would prevent access to AngularJS $scope from browser console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console, angularjs-scope

I've done a couple projects in the past that use AngularJS. In development, I was always able to call $scope in the browser console and thus all of its variables. For example, `$scope.myArray` would return something like `[]` or `[object1, object2]`.

However, now when I type in `$scope`, I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

I've also looked at other posts like [How to access the $scope variable in browser's console using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-scope-variable-in-browsers-console-using-angularjs), and it is suggested to use `angular.element($0).scope()`, but when I type that in the console, I get:

> undefined

and I can't access objects like `myArray` even though I know it is being created. Does anyone know what changed?

EDIT: I'm running into this problem also when I try code from previous projects that I were once able to access $scope for, so that makes me think it's not a simple implementation error.

Comment: Check this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data

Comment: it still works with dependency injection, any place that's in-play

Comment: It's likely that `$0` does not refer to the proper element. Find a selector for your element (e.g. by inspecting the element, right clicking on it in the "Elements" panel, and clicking "Get CSS path"), and doing `angular.element(theCssPath).scope()`.

Comment: I use AngularJS Batarang in chrome, this enables me to type `$scope` in the console. Did you not perhaps also use this extension, and accidentally forgotten about the extension after uninstalling it?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt Thanks for suggesting Batarang. This will help me with debugging, even though I would still like to have my old ability to just call `$scope` from within the console.

Comment: @Reuben using Batarang(or any other chrome extension) is the only way I know of accessing `$scope` in the console. Please see this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-scope-variable-in-browsers-console-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the definition of the controller put `window.myScope = $scope`. Then in the console you can call `myScope.myArray` to have things returned to you.

For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
window.myScope = $scope; //this allows console access

$scope.myArray = [];
//more code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$0 is a reference to the selected DOM node in the elements tab, so by doing this you get the selected DOM node scope printed out in the console.

You must get the element first.
Or you can just get the specified scope.
ex:

```
angular.element('‪#‎element‬').scope();
```

or

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]).scope()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fatb8g3z/

Comment: I still was not able to get this to work. I typed in `angular.element("button").scope();` and got this: `Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/jqLite/nosel`

Comment: That's jqLite's problem. Try this.
angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]).scope()