# How to access model variables in AngularJs without creating a module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

Okay, so here is a sample hello world code from the angularjs homepage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, this model variable `yourName` must have been created somewhere (in some scope), and it certainly can't be accessed using:

```
<script>
         console.log(yourName);
</script>
```

How can we access this variable, WITHOUT creating a module and assigning a controller to it, and then accessing it using `$scope.yourName`

Not that this is a requirement, but I certainly need it to clear some concepts.

Comment: you want to access yourName without controller ? isn't it the violation of MVC pattern which Angularjs is based upon?

Comment: this certainly isn't a good practice, but assuming if we COULD, how would we do it. Basically, want to understand how angular works in the scenario when we just use the directive ng-app, without assigning it a module.

Comment: This answer may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13744085/1362136 (it's basically the same idea as Austin's duplicate source)

Comment: @Austin yep, this does work angular.element($0).scope().yourName;

Comment: So, basically this is what is happening:

Angular encounters the directive ng-app, and it creates a root scope for the application. The variable 'yourname' is inside the root scope, since there is no other scope created in the app. The expression angular.element(<some selector>).scope() gives me the scope associated with the element selected, which in this case happens to be the root scope, and I can access the variable from the root scope.

Thanks @StephenByrne for the pointers

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that it's "evil" to try to do what you're doing, but I've been in a similar situation with legacy code that can't be rewritten. From what I gather though, you'd like to access a controller variable from outside of Angular.

Because the controller is an instance, you can't really access it from outside of Angular. You need a way to publish data from your internal model to outside of the scope of Angular. One way is to use a watch on that model and when it changes, assign it to a variable on "window". To do this, I'd suggest creating a separate Angular service to do the actual publishing, so the sins are better contained there.

```
$scope.$watch('yourName', function() {
    // If you have a Service to do this, you would use: 
    //myPublishService.publish("yourName", $scope.yourName)
    window.yourName = $scope.yourName;  
});
```

Comment: Nah! There is no controller involved here. Your answer does solve the problem of debugging scope variables, but that was not what I intended. Turns out that what I needed was already there in the documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope, under the section: "Retrieving Scopes from the DOM". Too bad I didn't find it earlier.