# AngularJS attributes values

Tags: angularjs

I 've just started to study Angular. Consider the following simple template:

```
<div ng-app ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
  <b>Invoice:</b>
  <div>
    Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" data-ng-model="qty">
  </div>
  <div>
    Costs: <input type="number" min="0" data-ng-model="cost">
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Total:</b> {{qty * cost | currency}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The attributes values e.g. `qty` and `cost` must be stored inside some variables, isn't it? **Which ones and how may I access them through the console?**

Comment: You can store them in a controller. Controllers are an essential part of coding with AngularJS. I suggest you read up on AngularJS essentials.

Comment: $scope.qty and $scope.cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a controller and store these values there.

In your JS file

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp');
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.qty = 1;
    $scope.cost = 2;
}]);
```

In your HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
   <b>Invoice:</b>
   <div>
       Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" data-ng-model="qty">
   </div>
   <div>
       Costs: <input type="number" min="0" data-ng-model="cost">
   </div>
   <div>
       <b>Total:</b> {{qty * cost | currency}}
   </div>
</div>
```

For your second query -  [detailed post on checking scope variables in Console.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-scope-variable-in-browsers-console-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

In your js file, you can access them with

`$scope.qty` and `$scope.cost`

For eg:

Mark your ng-app as myApp and add a ng-controller

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller = 'myController' ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
```

Create a js file named app.js with below content

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope)
{
    console.log($scope.qty);
    console.log($scope.cost);
});
```

You can see qty and cost logged in console

Comment: Is it possible to access them without adding a controller? Just using my plain template without any JS code and being able to see them, somehow, in console?

Comment: You can try {{qty}} below your Quantity input. As you type/change value in the quantity text box, {{qty}} updates. You can see it on browser. I am not sure if you can see it on console directly.

Answer (score 0):

All variables declared in AngularJS app are stored in $scope, you are able to access them trough **console.log($scope.qty)** from your controller.

However as you are declaring it in your template you by the time HTML has rendered JS is already loaded, therefore console returns "undefined". To understand the concept try:

```
$timeout(function() {
 console.log($scope.qty) 
}, 400);
```