# How to add a variable chained to $scope in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Suppose we have a variable defined as

```
 $scope.name = 'myName'
```

how can I return it from a function within JavaScript like so

```
function returnVar(){
alert 'this is the variable in Scope': name;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `return $scope.name` work?

Comment: Are you trying to access some element's scope from outside Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Below link for your solution:

https://coderwall.com/p/smkwhg/access-scope-outside-of-angularjs

Also Stackoverflow link which have same type of discussion:
[How do I access the $scope variable in browser's console using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-scope-variable-in-browsers-console-using-angularjs)