# Accessing an angular controller from the console (Chrome or Firefox)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, controller

I have attached a picture of the click action I want to run from the Chrome console, with various values passed.  The button is highlighted in gray top right in the inspect element.  It is the `savePublish()` function I want to learn how to access/use.

[image]

The button element is inside a `<div ng-controller="ProductEditCtrl as ctrl" .. >` container, but of course there are other controller wrappers on the page aliased as `ctrl`

My question is, how do I access the `savePublish()` method directly from the Chrome console?  And a bonus question-answer would be, how would I load the `ProductEditCtrl` controller and then call the savePublish method on a different page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access the $scope variable in browser's console using AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-do-i-access-the-scope-variable-in-browsers-console-using-angularjs)

Comment: Depending on your background and how you like to debug, you could also use the script debugging tool in the console to set break points in the code and inspect exactly what each variable is at each stage. Sometimes it's easier than console logging everything.

Answer (score 10):

Try - `angular.element($0).scope()` to inspect the `scope` of the button or you can use `Chrome` extenstion like [ng-inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj).

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-inspector/gjhmfjbfdbeeekiijofbikifokdkfhcc  - better then ng-inspector.

Comment: I see the `$0` in the inspection panel; is the `$0` because the element is highlighted?

Comment: Yes the inspected `element`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a controller via chrome console, via the elements class name by using angular.element.  EG:

`angular.element(document.querySelector(".btn.btn-primary")).controller()`

Associated methods/functions will be returned, if they are available on that element.