# Get current controller in use in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging, ngroute

I want to log the usage of different features in our Angularjs application.
Current feature in use is usually identified by the current route/url in browser but there are some features which open in a modal/popup or with ngInclude without change in route/url.

Is there any central way to identify which feature is in use currently, i thought of getting the current top level controller in use but unfortunately don't know how to get it.

Any other idea for that purpose?

P.S. I am using ngRoute.

Comment: Could you check if [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44154164/4927984) solved your issue? :)

Comment: @Mistalis sorry it didn't. I was looking for an application wide solution, and your solution doesn't cover all aspects. :(

Answer (score 2):

I see several way to log infos from/of the controller.

### 1) using `element.controller()`

From the docs of [`element.controller()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> **`controller(name)`** - retrieves the controller of the current element or its parent. By default retrieves controller associated with
>   the ngController directive. If `name` is provided as camelCase
>   directive name, then the controller for this directive will be
>   retrieved (e.g. `'ngModel'`).

You can this function on very element to get its parent controller. Here is an snippet example using a directive:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('MainController', function MainController() {});
app.controller('directiveCtrl', function directiveCtrl() {});

app.directive('controllerName', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<div>My controller name is: {{cName}}</div>',
      controller: 'directiveCtrl',
      link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
        var name;
        name = elem.controller().constructor.name;
        $scope.cName = name;
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div controller-name></div>
  </div>
  ***************************************************
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-controller="directiveCtrl">
      <div controller-name></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

## 2) using the console

You can access to every Angular object from your web console. For example, typing `angular.element($0).scope()` will get the current scope.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-do-i-access-the-scope-variable-in-browsers-console-using-angularjs), which is very complete about the use of the console.

## 3) logging from the controller

You can add a console call in your controller at the beginning of the code, and log whatever you want. This way, you will know each time a controller is instanciated:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.greetings = 'Hello world';
    console.log('MyCtrl instanciated!', $scope.greetings);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting and funny way of logging instantiated controllers

```
angular.module('yourModule')
.decorator('$controller', ['$delegate', function controllerDecorator($delegate) {
    return function loggingController (expression, locals, later, ident) {

        // Do all your logging here
        if (typeof (expression) === 'function') {
            console.log('Controller:' + expression.name);

        } else if (locals.$$controller) {
            console.log('Controller: ' + locals.$$controller);

        } else if (expression instanceof Array) {
            console.log('Controller:' + expression[expression.length - 1].name);

        } else {
            console.log('Controller:' + expression);
        }

        // fire regular controller function
        return $delegate(expression, locals, later, ident);
    };
}]);
```

What you are doing here is pretty much extending angulars controller function so you get certain functionality on all controllers, not only yours

Comment: Thanks, how can i use this as an injectable resource inside a factory to get the current controller name?

Comment: you just drop this piece of code somewhere in your app, its not something that you inject somewhere... but remember to **adjust module name**

Comment: if you managed to put it in use, please mark my answer as correct one, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Another way is injecting the `$route` service and calling:

```
$route.current.controller
```

Comment: This approach won't tell me if my feature is opened in a popup or with ngInclude..