# Angularjs how to find out which controllers are working at this moment

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to get list of working controllers at the moment? I have an object in my factory and also have controller, for example `"myController"`. So I need to make `myFactory.object={}`(make this object empty) if this controller is disconnected from the module.

Comment: $state.current.controller . How about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153816/get-current-controller-in-use-in-angularjs

Comment: Check out this question. It might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382734/get-controller-name-from-scope

Comment: It's not possible - some controllers don't even have names. Not a problem, since this is XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `$destroy` event which is bound on `$scope` of your controller to notify the factory.

An option could be something like this:

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'MyFactory', function($scope, MyFactory) {

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    MyFactory.object = {};
  })

}])
```

Comment: and if I use controller as construction instead of $scope I can write `this.$on('destroy....`, right?

Comment: @RoGGeR No. `this` isn't scope. There's no $on method, unless you defined it. $scope is supposed to be used in controllers. The preferable way is [$onDestroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) hook.

Answer (score 0):

in your factory use `_invokeQueue` to get the registered controllers, provides etc

```
angular.module('myModule')['_invokeQueue'].forEach(function(valu‌e){ 
      console.log(value[2][0]) 
      if(value[2][0] === "myController"){
          myFactory.object={} // make the factory object null 
      } 
})
```

Comment: what is function param `value`?

Comment: that is the array object pass by the foreach

Comment: sorry, I don't understand how it must exactly works. Can you explain more detailed please?

Comment: `['_invokeQueue']` returns a array . so in order to access the element inside array we need to use a loop. that is why foreach loop is there

Comment: I have a factory `app.factory('myFactory', function(){return{ obect:{} } })` I can't understand how I might use this checkup of working controllers :(

Comment: Why are you checking value[2][0] ? What is present at this indexes. Can you update your answer with more details?