# Some way to get Scope from angular.element with debugInfo turned off

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

There is some way to get `$scope` from `angular.element()` when the [debugInfoEnabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) is Disable.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('some-cool-element')).scope() // Undefined
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access the $scope variable in browser's console using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-do-i-access-the-scope-variable-in-browsers-console-using-angularjs)

Comment: I need to get the current scope from an element but I have the debugInfo disabled... So the .scope doesn't work for me

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to do this?