# Unable to update JS local variables in Sources window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Why do the local vars in Chrome's Sources tab have different names to what is in the JS code?
The local `n` is the `threadID` var in the JS code:
[image]

The trimmed down version of the code looks like this:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('az.controllers')
        .controller('threadViewCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope'
            function ($rootScope, $scope) {
                $scope.retrieveThreadMessages = function (companyReference, threadID) {                    
                    messagesApi.getMessages({ companyReference: companyReference, threadID: threadID, markAsRead: true }, function success(data) {
                    //Code omitted
                });
            };
    }]);
})();
```

Why am I unable to update the value of `n`?
I can double click the value, change it to something else, and it looks like it's been updated. But when I execute it and view the values used in the HTTP call in the Network tab, it used the old value.

How can I update `threadID` before making the HTTP GET request?

I'm using Chrome 91.0.4472.124 (Official Build) (64-bit), but have also had the same problem using Microsoft Edge.

I thought I could call the `$scope.retrieveThreadMessages()` function myself from Console, but `$scope` is undefined.

I tried using this code from one of the comments in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15756337/2063755), but I couldn't find `$scope`.

```
angular.element(document.body).scope()
```

Comment: there is no `n` in the code

Comment: and do not post only image of code.

Comment: @appleapple I'm well aware that there is no n in the code, hence why I am asking this question. The image is a screenshot showing you the value of n. I'll update the question with the code as well.

Comment: well the code never touch `n` so why you even bother update it?

Comment: `n` corresponds to `threadID`, and I want to update the value.